How to turn cookie recipe into brownie recipe?
What alterations should I make to my favorite cookie recipe (red velvet w/cream cheese chips) to turn it into a chewy gooey red velvet brownie w/cheese cake filling recipe?

Have you tried baking it as a bar cookie?  (Just filling the bottom of a sheet on or similar and baking it). They often end up chewier than if you just baked the cookies individually

I'm not sure "converting" the recipe is the best approach. I would find a good brownie recipe and add a cream cheese filling (or swirl even? this recipe has a cool technique). For the "red velvet" vibe just add food coloring.

According to children's TV, just replace baking powder with baking soda: https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/What%27s_Cooking%3F

You'll need to make several adjustments to both the ingredients and the baking method. Here's how you could do it:

Ingredients Adjustment:

For the brownie base, you'll need to modify the cookie dough into a brownie batter. Increase the amount of cocoa powder to enhance the chocolate flavor and achieve the characteristic red velvet color. You can use a combination of cocoa powder and red food coloring for the vibrant red hue.
Incorporate ingredients for a chewy, gooey texture. This includes adding extra eggs and adjusting the amount of flour to ensure a moist and fudgy consistency.
For the cheesecake filling, use cream cheese, sugar, and vanilla extract. Blend these ingredients until smooth to create a creamy and tangy cheesecake layer.


Layering the Brownie:

Spread half of the red velvet brownie batter evenly into a greased baking pan.
Pour the cheesecake filling over the brownie batter, spreading it evenly with a spatula.
Carefully spread the remaining brownie batter over the cheesecake filling, covering it completely.


Baking Method:

Preheat your oven to a temperature between 325°F (160°C) and 350°F (175°C), depending on the final texture you want.
keep in mind that the addition of the cheesecake layer may require slightly longer baking time. Check for doneness by inserting a toothpick into the brownie layer. It should come out with a few moist crumbs attached, but not completely clean, indicating that the brownies are fudgy and gooey.
Let the brownies cool completely before slicing.



To enhance the presentation and flavor, you can drizzle the cooled brownies with a cream cheese glaze or sprinkle them with powdered sugar.
Perhaps also add extra cream cheese chips or chopped nuts on top for added texture and flavor.
